# view sql when submit button is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know whether there is a way of viewing the sql submitted when the 'Submit' button is clicked in a rails form.

Thanks for any suggestion provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the log/development.rb file - you should be able to see the SQL of every request if you are in dev.

If you are in the console, enter this command at the start:

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

And you the log comments will be output to your screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the suggestions...got it :)

Answer (score 1):

The test log will show all database queries performed

```
tail -f log/test.log
```

Answer (score 1):

On my installation the sql statements are dumped into the development log (or the output of 'rails server'...